# How to make click effect in mobile with pure css

Tags: css, hover, click

Hey guys I'm a newbie to html and css. I'm trying to make mobile effect even though I have css effect for desktop. I want to make "**if someone click the section in mobile, change the background color to f5f5dc**". My current code is...

```
.section2 {
  height : auto;
  transition :0.2s;
  margin : 0.5em 0em 0.5em 0em;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 0.1px solid #302f2f34;
}
@media (hover: hover) { /* disable the effect on mobile phone */
  .section2:hover {
    transition :0.2s;
    transform: translate(2%, 0%);
    background-color: rgba(248, 123, 21, 0.264);
    cursor: pointer; } 
}
```

I know it would be easy if I use jQuery but I don't want to use jQuery... and is there a way to make the effect with pure css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@media` rule is for setting the min/max breakpoints to where the following rules should apply. You can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

To answer your question, to style an element only when it's clicked you may use the `:active` pseudo-selector. Like this:

```css
.section2:active {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! the :active pseudo-selector worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of "cheat" it using `tabindex` and the `:focus` on your `@media` query.

```css
.section2 {
  height: auto;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin: 0.5em 0em 0.5em 0em;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 0.1px solid #302f2f34;
}

.section2:hover {
  transition: 0.2s;
  transform: translate(2%, 0%);
  background-color: rgba(248, 123, 21, 0.264);
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .section2:focus {
    transition: 0.2s;
    transform: translate(2%, 0%);
    background-color: rgba(248, 123, 21, 0.264);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section2" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I divided mobile and desktop as you said and helped me a lot. Thanks!